# lstrip for hexadecimal numbers, how to?

Tags: python

I have been using Python to convert a number into its hexadecimal format and getting rid of the `'Ox'` prefix of each number by using `str.lstrip`; something like:

```
>>> data='0'
>>> data
'0'
>>> data=str(hex(int(data)))
>>> data
'0x0'
>>> data=data.lstrip("0x")
>>> data
''
```

The problem that I got here is that instead of printing `'0'`, it prints `''` after applying the `lstrip` method. My question is how can I do it so it prints `'0'`, instead of the empty string `''`? I need it in `str` type because I will store that data in a file.

Comment: Note that `lstrip("0x")` doesn't (just) strip the `'0x'`, it strips *all `0`s and `x`s* up to the leftmost character that is neither `0` nor `x`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know the `0x` prefix is there, you can remove it by using slicing:

```
>>> "0xdeadbeef"[2:]
'deadbeef'
```

Alternatively, you could use the string formatting operator instead of `hex()`:

```
>>> "%x" % 3735928559
'deadbeef'
```

or use `format()`:

```
>>> format(3735928559, "x")
'deadbeef'
```

Comment: you could also generalize the slicing solution: `lcut = lambda s, prefix: s[len(prefix):] if s.startswith(prefix) else s` - and I wonder why that's not in the standard library. Or is it, and I missed it?